# Dynamically add a frame to a userform page in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I am trying to dynamically create a frame within a page in Word VBA.

Say `oMultipage` is my multipage control in the userform, here's my code :

```vb
Dim oPage As MSForms.Page
Dim oFrame As MSForms.Frame

Set oPage = oMultipage.Page1
Set oFrame  = oPage.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame1")
With oFrame
    .Top = 12
    .Left = 12
    .Height = 18
    .Width = 200
    .Caption = "Frame 1"
End With
```

The code fails on the line `Set oFrame = oPage.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame1")` with the error

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
The object invoked has been disconnected from its clients.
```

Whether I click End or Debug, the Word app freezes then crashes, every time...

---

#### Edit

I replaced the faulty line by

```vb
Set oFrame = Me.oMultipage.Pages("Page1").Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame1")
```

and got the error

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method `Add` of object `Controls` failed
```

Comment: It may not be related, but you haven't assigned your multipage control to your object variable `oMultipage`.

Comment: @Domenic It could indeed but it is not. The code is from the UserForm module, therefore the MultiPage control variable already exists.

Comment: You can certainly refer to your multipage control by name.  However, if `oMultipage` is an object variable, you'll need to assign it your multipage control.  What is the name of your multipage control?

Comment: The name of the multipage is `oMultipage`, as I was trying to explain. Is is therefore available in the userform code as a variable. I know it is not the source of the problem because I previously used the multipage variable, without errors.

Comment: Okay, good, just wanted to make sure.  Also, when I run your code, it seems to work fine.